# In Pygraphviz, How can I assign edge colors according to edge weights?

Tags: python, networks, graphs

I am now drawing a weighted directed graph using Pygraphviz.

The adjacency matrix A of the weighted directed graph is

```
A = pd.DataFrame({'X': [0.0,0.1,-0.8], 'Y': [-0.7,0.0,-0.1], 'Z': 
    [0.4,0,-0.1]} ,index=["X", "Y", "Z"])
```

[image: A]

where A_{i,j} indicates the edge weight from the node i to the node j.

I was able to draw the graph without edge color.

```
import networkx as nx
from networkx.drawing.nx_agraph import to_agraph
from IPython.display import SVG, display

G_nx = nx.from_pandas_adjacency(A,create_using=nx.DiGraph())
G_nx.graph['edge'] = {'arrowsize': '1.0', 'splines': 'curved'}
G_nx.graph['graph'] = {'scale': '3'}


Agraph_eg = to_agraph(G_nx)                                                              
Agraph_eg .node_attr["height"] = 0.3
Agraph_eg .node_attr["width"] = 0.3
Agraph_eg .node_attr["shape"] = "circle"
Agraph_eg .node_attr["fixedsize"] = "true"
Agraph_eg .node_attr["fontsize"] = 8
Agraph_eg.layout(prog="neato")                                                                     
Agraph_eg.draw('graph_eg1.png')
```

[image: graph_eg1.png]

But I have no idea how to assign edge colors and widths according to the following two rules.

#1 If weights are more than 0, edge color should be red. If weight are less than 0, edge color should be blue.

#2 Edge widths should be proportional to the absolute values of weights.

Do you have any idea how to do this??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might help you

```
for edge in G_nx.edges(data=True):
    color = "black"
    weight = edge[2]["weight"]
    if weight > 0:
        color = "red"
    elif weight < 0:
        color = "blue"
    edge[2]["color"] = color
    edge[2]["penwidth"] = abs(weight)
```

This gives you the following graph:

[image]

Depending on your network size this solution might take some time. "penwidth" is the graphviz information for the edge width.

Comment: Thank you veru much !! It works !!

Comment: @Apppii092 if my answer solves your question could you please mark it as accepted?